# How should I correctly push my project to github using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github, gitlab, egit

I work in Eclipse. I have a maven project and usually, I commit and push it to my remote repo on GitLab. Now I want to push this project to a brand new GitHub repo. I've already created an empty repo on GitHub and pulled it to my local machine. So I already have a corresponding empty local repo too. The thing is I don't understand how to push my project to my new local repository and then push it to Github.
Usually, I use Egit but I can use the command line as well.
Maybe my logic is wrong? What should I do to have my project on GitHub then?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, if you were already pushing to GitLab with Egit. Have you tried to do it yet? Are you getting errors?

You should be able to use Egit the same way by committing to your local repo and then pushing to GitHub instead of GitLab.

The only difference would be having to use your GitHub credentials (or associating your SSH key to GitHub), and then specifying your GitHub repository.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial

The only thing that you had to keep in mind is to make sure your branch specs match. I think you might see "HEAD" by default, but you can change that to "master" if that's all you have.